# $.cookie('name') is not a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am trying to save and use a cookie to know what kind of viewStyle user wants. There is a swich for this cookie.

This is how I want to update the cookie

```
                $('body').on('click','.viewBy li a',function(){
                    if($('.titular').length > 0){
                         $.cookie('viewBy','titular',{expires:30});
                    }else{
                         $.cookie('viewBy','',{expires:30});
                    }
                });
```

And this is how i am checking

```
                if($.cookie('viewBy')){
                        $('.viewBy li').toggleClass('active');
                        $('.recetaTitular').addClass('titular');
                }
```

But i get this firebug error:

```
$.cookie is not a function
[Parar en este error]
```

I tried with

```
                if(typeof $.cookie('viewBy') != 'undefined' &&($.cookie('viewBy'))){
                        $('.viewBy li').toggleClass('active');
                        $('.recetaTitular').addClass('titular');
                }
```

But getting same error

Comment: how about `var cook = $.cookie('viewBy'); if (cook) ...` or perhaps you missed a script include?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$.cookie` is not a jQuery function. You need to include a plugin, perhaps this one:

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

**After** you load the jQuery plugin.